# how to make chat from the same in the same minute hide the user name

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

i have school assignment to create chat app like this,

[image]

it is now working, but now i want to make when user send multiple message in the same minute, the profile,username and minutes are hidden like in this example

[image]

anyone have any idea how? any suggestion would be very helpful

EDIT 1
Here's my html to show the chats

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages">
      <div [ngClass]="{ 'bot': message.author === 'bot',
      'user': message.author === 'user' }">
        <img *ngIf="message.author === 'bot'" class="avatar rounded-circle"
          src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/robot-face.png" alt="">
        <img *ngIf="message.author === 'user'" class="avatar rounded-circle" src="https://i.gifer.com/no.gif" alt="">
        <p style="padding: 0 !important;margin: 0 10px;font-weight: 500;">{{ message.author }}</p>

        <time class="time">{{ message.time }}</time>
      </div>
      <div class="message" [ngClass]="{ 'from': message.author === 'bot',
    'to': message.author === 'user' }">
        <!-- Text -->
        <p style="padding: 0 i !important;margin: 0 !important;word-wrap: break-word;" *ngIf="message.type == 'text'">{{
          message.content }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

in my chat.service i have this code

```
export class Message {
  constructor(
    public content: any,
    public time: string,
    public type: any,
    public author: string,
  ) { }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you do not share code, there is no way we can help you.

Comment: my bad, i'll edit my answer

Comment: You may have to change the array structure, so you can group messages by date. So each item of this array would have a `messagesDate: string` attribute, and a `messages: Message[]` attribute.

Comment: i have `time` inside my array

Comment: for now, you may have 10 items in your array, where 5 have the same `time` attribute. You have to change it so there is only 6 items in your array, and each item have an unique `time` attribute, and instead of a `content` attribute, you would have a `contents` attribute. Then you'll have to handle that new structure of array in your HTML.

Comment: why changing to `contents`

Comment: what i have in mind is, how if i check if the new message time stamp in minute is the same as the last one, then set *ngIf to profile, and time container, is that how it works?

Comment: You could do the check in the `*ngFor` indeed, but that would compute it on any UI event. Doing it only once is better. What I mean by replacing `content` by `contents` is to contain an array of content instead of only 1 content. When I say you would have 6 items instead of 10, it means 5 items would have a `contents` with only 1 content in it, and the 6th item would have an array of 5 content

Comment: i dont understand why i would have 6 items instead of 10? whats the difference?

Comment: Well, you have only 6 different dates. So you make 1 item for each date. So you can loop on those items, and only display once the date. Then, under each date, you may have 1 or multiple messages. So you can loop on `contents` to display each message related to this date.

Comment: i see, so it loops the time to get the contents, not the other way round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide that you can use this

```
<time class="time" *ngIf="message.time !== messages[i - 1].time  || message.author !== messages[i-1]?.author">
                {{ message.time | date:'shortTime' }}
    </time>
```

hide the element if the time or the user is different

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a 2 step process where you first pre-process the messages using js to properly populate necessary fields, then using these fields in the HTML as follows:
In your typescript code you can use this code :

```
export class Message {
         constructor(
           public content: any,
           public time: string,
           public type: any,
           public author: string,
           public group?: {
            //  This stores the message position within the group 
             pos: number;
           }
         ) {}
       }
```

Filter function:

```
 filter(messages: Message[]) {
    messages.forEach((m, i) => {
      // check if the author is the same
      if (m.author == messages[i - 1].author) {
        // check if it has been sent within the same minute
        var diff = Math.abs(
          new Date(m.time).getMilliseconds() -
            new Date(messages[i - 1].time).getMilliseconds()
        );
        if (diff < 60000) {
          // check if this is the first message from this author in this group
          if (messages[i - 1].group) {
            m.group = {
              pos: messages[i - 1].group.pos + 1
            };
          } else {
            m.group = {
              pos: 0
            };
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Chats HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages">
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'bot': message.author === 'bot',
  'user': message.author === 'user' }" *ngIf="!message.group || message.group?.pos == 0">
    <img *ngIf="message.author === 'bot'" class="avatar rounded-circle"
      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/robot-face.png" alt="">
    <img *ngIf="message.author === 'user'" class="avatar rounded-circle" src="https://i.gifer.com/no.gif" alt="">
    <p style="padding: 0 !important;margin: 0 10px;font-weight: 500;">{{ message.author }}</p>

    <time class="time" *ngIf="!message.group || message.group?.pos == 0">{{ message.time }}</time>
  </div>
  <div class="message" [ngClass]="{ 'from': message.author === 'bot',
'to': message.author === 'user' }">
    <!-- Text -->
    <p style="padding: 0 i !important;margin: 0 !important;word-wrap: break-word;" *ngIf="message.type == 'text'">{{
      message.content }}
    </p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

This solution can be easily modified to be used in a pipe so that this evaluation is only done when rendering, or in case you need different kinds of groupings so that params can be passed

Comment: omg thanks for an helpful answer, but what's the difference with the first answer? i mean, the first one is really simple to use

Comment: Several:
1. The first one only bunches the timestamp together, while mine also hides the avatar as well, which I believe is required from the image provided
2. It can be extended for other types of groupings
3. It can be modified to be used in a pipe
4. If implemented at the service level, computation only occurs when data changes, unlike the other one where computation is repeated every time the page is rendered

But then again, the simpler answer may just work for you so...

Comment: actually i wrap the avatar, username also the timestamp with a div, then add the first answer to that div so it hides the avatar username and timestamp. For now i think it's simpler to use the first one, but your solution is more advance i can learn from that, thanks tho